# Return a pandas dataframe and invoke from main (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, program-entry-point

I have the following code for readVision.py:

```
import pandas as pd
#Read csv files
vision = pd.read_csv('path/vision.csv')
vision = vision[vision['gaze_x'].notnull()]
vision = vision[vision['gaze_y'].notnull()]
vision = vision[vision['pupil_axis1'].notnull()]
vision = vision[vision['pupil_axis1'].notnull()]
vision = vision[vision['pupil_area'].notnull()]

#Then I make other changes to Vision
if __name__ == "__main__":
    return vision
```

Then, I have main.py:

```
import readVision
print vision
```

It is possible to use vision dataframe in main, with all the changes made in readVision.py? I want to use the modified dataframe in main, but i don't know how to return it from readVision.py. 
Help please!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in readVision.py into a function, and then importing that function iside of main.py:

```
# readVision.py
def vision(path):
  vision = pd.read_csv(path)
  vision = vision[vision['gaze_x'].notnull()]
  vision = vision[vision['gaze_y'].notnull()]
  vision = vision[vision['pupil_axis1'].notnull()]
  vision = vision[vision['pupil_axis1'].notnull()]
  vision = vision[vision['pupil_area'].notnull()]
  return vision
```

Then you can import and call the `vision` function inside of your main.py module.

```
# main.py
from readVision import vision
v = vision("path/vision.csv")
print type(v)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```